# Get client domain name from request in node.js & express.js on backend

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to get a client's host domain on backend side.
e.g.

- frontend (http://localhost:3000)
- backend (http://localhost:4000)

On frontend side, send api request to backend using ajax.

```
$.get('http://localhost:4000/auth');
```

On backend side, I did like this.

```
// routes/auth.js

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers.host);
...
});
...
module.exports = router;
```

this is my `app.js` in backend.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.js');
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
...
```

Expected result:

```
localhost:3000
```

Current result:

```
localhost:4000
```

It shows backend url.

When I did console.log(req.headers), it's the following.

- Request from Postman

```
{ 'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.17.1',
  accept: '*/*',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': '5eb5791e-3a5a-4285-83c9-33320d935a2e',
  host: 'localhost:4000',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  cookie:
   'connect.sid=s%3A5DIRzqn5HVL3vra410YJ6I56uo9qIj2M.6OWL8rKr1peEMz60sakejaeJJNgv5LQFUKypA6cCXLQ',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

- Request from Frontend

```
{ host: 'localhost:4000',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'application/json' }
```

Is there something I did wrong? Please someone help me.

Comment: You got the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**create a custom header 'xyz' or any name of your choice and assign the url in client side while sending the request.
In server access it like  req.get('xyz').**

with already available stuff, I wasn't able to get port.

```
req.protocol + '://' + req.host + req.originalUrl
```

Comment: If client domain is changed, we need to change header again.

Comment: @AllenHaley that's not a problem as you are gonna set the header whenever u make the request

Comment: @Sudhakr RS, this wasn't what I am looking for but this is also solution. Thank you.

Comment: `req.headers.host` will return the hostname:port tested in express v4!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to receive the clients current URL as this is not inlcuded by default in the request header. The `host` header is pointing the target domain the request is intended for and not the current URL of the client application.

Instead, you need to add the current URL, also here called `window.location` to your request by defining a custom header:

```js
// please be aware, that according to the documentation, you cannot use `$.get(...)` here. Use https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ instead.
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:4000/auth",
    headers: {"X-Window-Location": window.location}
});
```

And on the backend side:

```js
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers['X-Window-Location']);
...
});
```